# Telerik Kendo grid-export to excel is not responding when trying to export more than 4000 records to excel

Tags: excel, telerik-grid

Kendo grid-export to excel is not responding when trying to export more than 4000 records to excel... And its not even throwing an error message ... Can someone please advice or suggest a work around for this.

Here is the code for Kendo grid

```
                            @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("Billinggrid")

        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.groupid).Width(75).Filterable(true).Sortable(true).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" });
            columns.Bound(c => c.groupname).Width(125).Filterable(true).Sortable(true).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" });
            columns.Bound(c => c.groupeffectivedate).Width(90).Filterable(true).Sortable(true).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" });
            columns.Bound(c => c.recipientdatareceived).Width(95).Filterable(true).Sortable(true).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" });
            columns.Bound(c => c.recipientsent).Width(100).Filterable(true).Sortable(true).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" });
            columns.Bound(c => c.accountmanager).Width(125).Filterable(true).Sortable(true).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" });
            columns.Bound(c => c.billinggroup).Width(75).Filterable(true).Sortable(true).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" });
            columns.Bound(c => c.reportyearmonth).Width(85).Filterable(true).Sortable(true).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" });
            columns.Bound(c => c.recordcount).Width(55).Filterable(false).Sortable(true).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" });
            columns.Bound(c => c.datafilecount).Width(50).Filterable(false).Sortable(true).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" });
            columns.Bound(c => c.datacharge).Format("{0:c}").Filterable(false).Sortable(false).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" });
            columns.Bound(c => c.printcharge).Format("{0:c}").Filterable(false).Sortable(false).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" });
            columns.Bound(c => c.insertcharge).Format("{0:c}").Filterable(false).Sortable(false).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" });
            columns.Bound(c => c.envelopecharge).Format("{0:c}").Filterable(false).Sortable(false).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" });
            columns.Bound(c => c.postage).Format("{0:c}").Filterable(false).Sortable(false);
            columns.Bound(c => c.total).Format("{0:c}").Filterable(false).Sortable(false);
            columns.Bound(c => c.postageremaining).Width(95).Format("{0:c}").Filterable(true).Sortable(true).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" });
        })

        .Resizable(resizable => resizable.Columns(true))
        .Reorderable(reorderable => reorderable.Columns(true))
        .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 25, 50, 100, 500 })
            .Messages(messages => messages.ItemsPerPage(" items displayed"))
            )
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height("auto"))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "Font-size:x-small" })

        //.ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())
        .Excel(excel => excel
            .FileName("Billing_Report-" + DateTime.Now + ".xlsx")
            .AllPages(true)
            //.Filterable(true)
            .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "Report"))
            )
        //.Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))

        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
```

Comment: I have met same problem. However my grid stopped exporting from 2000 records (but I had about 40 columns).. Since it is exporting through client side I assume that it will be some memory problem ... Unfortunately I didn't solve it ... I am just disabling telerik exports button from some amount of records. So I am voting up, this question is interesting for me aswell.

Answer (score 0):

From the post in telerik forum [System Out of Memory](http://www.telerik.com/forums/system-out-of-memory)

When OpenAccess executes a query the actual retrieval of results is split into chunks. There is a fetch size that determines the number of records that are read from the database in a single pass. With a query that returns a lot of records this means that the fetch size is not exceeded and not all 40 000 records will be retrieved at one time in memory. Iterating over the result data you will get  several reads from the database until the iteration is over. However, when you iterate over the result set subsequent reads are accumulated when you keep references to the objects that are iterated. 
An out of memory exception may be caused when you operate with all the records from the grid. The way to avoid such an error would be to work with the data in chunks. For example, a paging for the grid and an option that exports data sequentially from all pages will achieve this. The goal is to try to reduce the objects kept in-memory at a time and let the garbage collection free unneeded memory. A LINQ query with Skip() and  Take() is ideal in such cases where having all the data in-memory is costly.